# Send form contents to the admin's email

Tags: 7, forms

I have created the form using custom module, and it is working fine now. In this case, when I submit the form it simply sends the mail to the particular person from particular id. For this what i did is,

```
function custom_form_my_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
$valid_email = $form_state['values']['email'];
$from = 'karthik.k.siva@gmail.com';
$body = 'Email: '.$valid_email.'<br />URL: '.request_uri();
$to = 'karthikeyan.ameex@gmail.com'; // Set this email address - emails will be sent to this email address! 
$params = array(
'body' => $body,
'subject' => 'Website Information Request',
);

if (drupal_mail('custom_form_my_form', 'some_mail_key', $to, language_default(), $params, $from, TRUE))
{
    drupal_set_message('Thanks, we will be in contact with more information soon.');     
} else {
    drupal_set_message('There was an error subscribing you. Please try again later');
}
```

}

And now I want to receive the submitted form contents through email, for that what I have to do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement [`hook_mail`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_mail/7) too and define `some_mail_key` in your `hook_mail` :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_mail().
 */
function mymodule_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  if ($key == 'some_mail_key') {
    $message['subject'] = $params['subject'];
    $message['body'][] = $params['body'];
  }
}
```

Then you can use `drupal_mail` function like :

```
drupal_mail('mymodule', 'some_mail_key', $to, language_default(), $params, $from, TRUE);
```

Change `mymodule` with your module's name.

Comment: Still, I am getting the same result.

Comment: Did you cleared the cache?? Can I see your code??